# How to use docker with drupal and drush?

Tags: drupal, docker, docker-compose, drupal-8, drush

I'd like to use [drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush). It needs to run in the drupal container. There's also a [drush docker repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/drush/drush). But I have no clue how to make it available whithin the drupal container. It's my first docker and drupal project, so maybe I'm getting things completely wrong.

How can I use drush with this drupal docker image?
https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/
Is it possible to manage it with docker-compose? Maybe extending the drupal container?

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.5
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_USER=xxxxx
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=xxxxxx

drupal:
  image: drupal:8.0.4
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you provide more information about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to use drush (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush). It needs to run in the drupal container. There's also a drush docker repo (https://hub.docker.com/r/drush/drush/). But I have no clue how to make it available whithin the drupal container. It's my first docker and drupal project, so maybe I'm getting things completely wrong.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as @citizen404.

Answer (score 11):

I have spent way too much time getting this to work. Here are my findings.

Like OP I never got the drush image to work on the local docker network so it seemed simpler to me to bundle drush via composer with the drupal image (see Dockerfile below).

That works somewhat, if you exec into the container you can run drush status, but it won't connect to the mysql server. There are two reasons for this:

1. The package mysql-client is needed to connect remotely to the database (since we are running this on a local docker network).
2. The mysql hostname needs to be explicitly set in the docker-compose file (or docker run command).

---

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM drupal:8.3.7-apache

# Install packages
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    curl \
    wget \
    vim \
    git \
    unzip \
    mysql-client

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    ln -s /root/.composer/vendor/bin/drush /usr/local/bin/drush

# Install Drush
RUN composer global require drush/drush && \
    composer global update

# Clean repository
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

The important packages are `curl` (obviously) and `mysql-client`.

And these are the relevant parts of the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  drupal:
    image: drupal
    build: ./docker/drupal
    env_file:
      - ./docker/environment.env
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    volumes:
      - ./docker/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
    env_file:
      - ./docker/intervention/environment.env
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    build: ./docker/mysql
    env_file:
      - ./docker/environment.env
    hostname: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql-data-d8:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always

volumes:
  mysql-data-d8:
```

#### Why explicitly setting the hostname works

The second problem above is particularly devilish since drush use the configuration from settings.php to connect to mysql. But the 'host' key in the databases array is interpreted differently by drupal and drush apparently. Here is the relevant section from `settings.php`:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => array (
    'default' => array (
      'database' => $envs['MYSQL_DATABASE'] ?? '',
      'username' => $envs['MYSQL_USER'] ?? '',
      'password' => $envs['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] ?? '',
      'host' => 'mysql',//php_sapi_name() === 'cli' ? 'a8597b38be21' : 'mysql',
      'port' => '3306',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => 'drupal_',
      'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
      'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
      'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
    ),
  ),
);
```

The out commented line after `'host' => 'mysql'` is a previous attempt taken from another SO answer and illustrates the problem, drush use the command line server API which is different from whatever drupal uses. The alternate hostname is the hash id of the running container, which can be found by running the sql (from phpmyadmin for example):

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname'` (taken form [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/129635/how-do-i-find-out-what-my-ip-address-of-my-mysql-host-is))

This value changes every time the container is updated, so to make it persist, the hostname is explicitely stated in `docker-compose.yml`, se above.

---

Edit: I've made a small project to host a drupal + drush + phpmyadmin development environment based on this: https://github.com/glaux/drupal8docker

Comment: Why is it the first thing you do in your Dockerfile is remove `/bin/sh`? It's such a tiny binary. Seems odd.

Comment: @Jack_Hu Honestly I have no idea. That bit is copied from an example I found long ago and I haven’t given it a second thought.

Comment: thank you! I have been trying to figure this out for a while now

Comment: @Jack_Hu /bin/sh is not simply removed. It is replaced with a symbolic link to /bin/bash. See the second command in the chain: rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, I see that... But still. It's not using any bash features, and even if it were, setting bash as the default shell, or specifying `/bin/bash` explicitly, or a whole host of other options is preferable. Subtly altering the system, so you *think* that some code is being execute in a standard POSIX shell, and instead it's *actually* being run in bash, is just a terrible idea. Probably one that three or four years down the line you'll be *bash*ing (no pun intended) your head against a wall, wondering why a parameter is being expanded, when you're explicitly running it in `sh`.

Comment: @Jack_Hu I completely agree on that. It's just that your first comment did not state that so explicitly... :-)

Answer (score 5):

As always with Docker there are many options to use drush. 
But notice that in order **drush to have access to the database** (eg mysql) there should be volumes from mysql container on Drupal such as:

```
 version: '2'
 services:
   drupal:
     image: drupal:8.0.4-apache
     volumes_from:
       - mysql
   mysql:
     image: mysql
     volumes:
       - /var/lib/mysql
       - /usr/bin
...
```

Here are the most common.

1) Mount your **local drush** to the Drupal container:

```
version: '2'
services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal:8.0.4-apache
    volumes:
      # Mount local drush to your container.
      - /usr/local/bin/drush:/drush/drush
```

2) Create a **data only docker image for drush** and volume the executable to your Drupal container. See an example at https://github.com/RobLoach/drush-docker/issues/32#issuecomment-222321265.

3) Install Drush into Drupal container after it has run. Eg:

```
$ docker exec -ti <MY_DRUPAL_CONTAINER> \ 
bash -c 'php -r "readfile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.drush.org/drush.phar');" \
> drush  && chmod +x drush && mv drush /usr/local/bin'
```

4) Install Drush on Drupal by **creating a Docker image** (using a Dockerfile). Example:

```
FROM drupal:8.0.4-apache

MAINTAINER ...

RUN php -r "readfile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush \
&& chmod +x drush \
&& mv drush /usr/local/bin
```

5) Use **another container with drush** and **volume it** to the Drupal container using the docker-compose.yml. Example:

```
version: '2'
services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal:8.0.4-apache
    volumes_from:
      - drush
  drush:
    image: drush/drush
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/bin/drush
      - /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: I tried approach 5, but it failed with this error: ERROR: for drush  Cannot create container for service drush: b'cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/overlay2/37b3bf71181740b62dcd1e0ca812caf1aab398228cd2a22fc7803954d8765b70/merge
d/usr/local/bin/drush'

Comment: #4 worked like a charm. Already had the Dockerfile, so it was a no brainer. Thanks!

Comment: @GuyPaddock I believe #5 in the answer is incorrect; you cannot mount a file as a volume. See [here](https://github.com/RobLoach/drush-docker/issues/32#issuecomment-222321265): "Normally you could volume the drush executable from drush/drush image but you can't do this since mount is not allowed for files."

Answer (score 4):

In order to make Drush work effectively - you're better off running it from within the container that is running Drupal. For that, add a one liner in your Dockerfile.

```
# Set base Image/tag here. 
FROM drupal:8-fpm 
# Get a global installation of Drush on the web / drupal container 
RUN php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush && chmod +x drush && mv drush /usr/bin/
```

For actual usage, you're better off shipping separate Drush aliases for usage - both from the container and the host (via public key SSH). As an example, look at these aliases and consider the entire setup as a reference implementation: https://github.com/srijanaravali/docker-blueprint/blob/master/docker-utils/drush/local.aliases.drushrc.php

You can transport these aliases into the container by having something like this in your Dockerfile:

```
# Push our aliases into the container ~/.drush 
ADD /path/to/your/drush-aliases/* ~/.drush/
```

or - for shared control with the host, you can consider having it mounted as a volume in your docker-compose.yml.

```
volumes:
  - ~/.drush/:/root/.drush/
```

You can now run Drush commands on the container like this: `docker exec drush @alias <command>`. You can bash alias that to be something less keyboard intensive, ofcourse.

Or, Use drush from your host by invoking the SSH alias you shipped instead - `drush @alias-ssh <command>`

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions for Drupal 8 - Docker - Drush combo is:

1. Step: Installing the Drush in the image where you have the Apache server, let's call this docker image 'php5'.
2. Step: make an alias in your ~/.bashrc file like this:

   ```
   alias dr5='docker-compose run php5 /root/.composer/vendor/bin/drush --root=/var/www/html/docroot';
   ```

In this alias i use the Docker composer but it is the same with simple Docker, you runt the Drush command on the php5 image specifying where your  drush is in Docker and where your codebase is on Docker. 
In this way you just use it like this:

```
dr5 cr
```

For the cache rebuild command, in you local code directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal. For me is very useful and flexible thing to develop Drupal with Docker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options, you could run the `drush/drush` container separately and use a shared hold volume so it has access to the files that drupal is going to use.

Or you could build a new image that contains both drush and drupal. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerimages/

You can probably use the Dockerfile for the drush image and the drupal image as guidance.

Answer (score 0):

What I chose to do, is install it will composer in my `web` container.

First, I install composer and then I require Drush in the directory that I want.

Dockerfile example:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
    && php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '93b54496392c062774670ac18b134c3b3a95e5a5e5c8f1a9f115f203b75bf9a129d5daa8ba6a13e2cc8a1da0806388a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" \
    && php composer-setup.php \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN cd /var/www/html \
    && composer require drush/drush
```

If Drush is already a dependency within the composer.json of your project you can just `composer install` it.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to create your own image based on your actual container, include all the changes you want like drush, nano, vim, etc and push them in your own docker repo. To do that follow these:
https://www.scalyr.com/blog/create-docker-image/
https://ropenscilabs.github.io/r-docker-tutorial/04-Dockerhub.html

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways, i highly recommend using DDEV
checkout the installation process:
https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/ddev-installation/

After installation for LINUX:
mkdir my-drupal10-site

```
cd my-drupal10-site

ddev config --project-type=drupal10 --docroot=web --create-docroot

ddev start 

ddev composer create drupal/recommended-project

ddev composer require drush/drush

ddev drush site:install --account-name=admin --account-pass=admin -y

ddev drush uli

ddev launch
```

here drush can be easily installed using composer command.